# Can changing APN settings in Android improve internet speed?

Tags: mobile-network, apn

I wonder while reading some of blogs and even people around me suggests some changes in APN settings(that includes *APN Name, MCC, MNC, APN Protocol and Bearer*), claiming that will increase my internet speed.

If this is a real solution for increasing internet speed, do above settings are enough to change?

Additional Info: Country India 
Carrier Network- Jio/Airtel